# Undefined reference to SDL_mixer functions

Tags: c++, g++, sdl, sdl-mixer

I'm learning SDL right now, and I want to play an MP3 file with `SDL_mixer`, so I installed it, but when I compile my program I get "undefined reference" errors for every SDL mixer function I use.

Here is my compile command:

```
g++ Player.cpp -o Player -L/opt/lib -I/usr/include/SDL -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_REENTRANT -lSDL `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs`
```

If I add `-lSDL_mixe` to this, it reports that it cannot find it.

Comment: You'd say `-lSDL_mixer`?

Comment: Yes that is what I meant^^ meanwhile, I figured it out, the problem was I was using -lSDL_mixer instead of -lSDL2_mixer. My Command now looks like this: g++ Player.cpp -o Player -L/opt/lib `sdl2-config --cflags --libs` -lSDL2 -lSDL2_mixer `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs`

Comment: *it reports that it cannot find it* - can you? Is there a `libSDL_mixer.so` or `libSDL_mixer.a` file in your library search paths?

Comment: Fixed some grammar and capitalization; removed `code` formatting from things that are *not* code or command-line text.